# New room instance when different users logins with the same device

Tags: firebase, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I give you some background about what I am doing. I am working in a project where two type os users can login(a patient and a doctor). Both of them can share some type of information. I am using firebase to login the users and to share information between them and room to make patient posible to store some of his records. The little problem is when I am login with a different patient those records apear in the new user. So i was wonder if there is a way to make different room instances for different users logged in . Here you have the room database in code.

-->Room database provider using dependency injection.

```
@Module @InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class) object DatabaseModule {

@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideDatabase(
    @ApplicationContext context: Context
) = Room.databaseBuilder(
    context,
    UserCancerDatabase::class.java,
    DATABSE_NAME
).build()

@Singleton
@Provides
fun providesDao(database: UserCancerDatabase) = database.cancerDataDao()}
```

---> Database

```
@Database(
entities = [CancerDataEntity::class, UVEntity::class],
version = 1,
exportSchema = false)@TypeConverters(UserCancerDataTypeConverter::class, UVDataTypeConverter::class) abstract class UserCancerDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
abstract fun cancerDataDao(): DataDao}
```

--->DAO

```
@Dao interface DataDao {

/**** PRE-DIAGNOSTIC CANCER DATA *****/
@Query("SELECT * FROM cancer_data_table")
fun readCancerData():kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow<List<CancerDataEntity>>

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun insertCancerRecord(cancerDataEntity: CancerDataEntity)

@Delete
suspend fun deleteCancerRecord(cancerDataEntity: CancerDataEntity)

@Query("DELETE FROM cancer_data_table")
suspend fun deleteAllCancerRecords()

/******* RADIATION WEATHER DATA *********/
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun insertRadiationWeatherData(uvEntity: UVEntity)
@Query("SELECT * FROM RADIATION_WEATHER_TABLE")
fun readRadiationWeatherData(): Flow<UVEntity>}
```

Comment: Sure! I am new here! Thanks for your advice :)

Answer (score 1):

> So i was wonder if there is a way to make different room instances for different users logged in

Assuming that you mean different databases then yes, simply use a different database name when invoking the databaseBuilder e.g.

```
fun provideDatabase(
    @ApplicationContext context: Context,
    databaseNameForUser: String
) = Room.databaseBuilder(
    context,
    UserCancerDatabase::class.java,
    databaseNameForUser
).build()
```

Comment: Sorry for give feedback now...Really appreciate your help. I have not tested it yet but when i'll do i give feedback to you. Merry christmas :)